# PHP IF Statements Error is_string

Tags: php, if-statement, statements

I've been studying PHP using only the internet, so I've been experiencing errors.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lg = $_POST['lg'];
if (is_string($name) && is_numeric($lg)) {
    header( "Location: portal.php?ejhbusbhdubr=nennuncuiecbdhbcvhebchebcdjebcdsjhbcebhfcvebhdchebhcvhervbhecbvecveh" ) ;
}
if (empty($name) && is_numeric($lg)) {
    echo "Please enter your name.";
}
else {
   header ("Location: index.php?invalid=true");
}
?>
```

I'm having problems with the second if statement. What I'm trying to do is that I'm trying to make an error message appear when the `$name variable` is left empty, and the `$lg` variable isn't. I think the is_string variable handler's the problem here. Perhaps a string can be empty. But as I said, since I don't have a book, I don't know what to change it too.

In case you still don't get what I mean,

```
Name: ""
LG: "1234"
```

I want the above to return as error. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read: http://nl3.php.net/is_string, look at: is_string('') = bool(true)

Comment: is_string() doesn't care about contents. It's basically looking at the internal TYPE of the variable. if `var_dump($var)` says string, then `is_string($var)` will say TRUE. if var_dump says something else, then is_string will be false.

Comment: Guys, someone suggested using strlen. I can't seem to find it now, but it does work. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try to write you condition like this:

```
if (empty($name) && !empty($lg))
```

Comment: he isnt using a string for $lg, he is using numbers.

Comment: Why are you so sure ? There is no post variables validation shown.

Comment: cause as he said, it is a variable, so its numberic, not a string of letters.

Comment: What if somebody posts 0x539 ? This is a numeric TRUE for is_numeric, but if you echo gettype($_POST[$possiblynumeric]) you get "string"

Comment: he isnt using it that way though, hes using strictly numbers.

Comment: Since he's been "studying PHP using only internet" it would be a good practice to teach him never to trust any input.

Comment: i realize that, but he has found a solution to his current problem. So this small discussion we are having is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this, I just moved your if over the first one, and changed it a bit. You have to test if the string is empty before testing, if it is a string. I mean is_string will return true even if the string is empty.

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$lg = $_POST['lg'];

if (empty(trim($name)) && is_numeric($lg)) {
    echo "Please enter your name.";
}
elseif(is_numeric($lg)) {
    header( "Location: portal.php?ejhbusbhdubr=nennuncuiecbdhbcvhebchebcdjebcdsjhbcebhfcvebhdchebhcvhervbhecbvecveh" ) ;
    die();
}

else {
   header ("Location: index.php?invalid=true");
   die();
}
```